# Проблема со стилями css и flex-box

Tags: css3, html5, flexbox

Пробую верстать небольшой лендинг, подключил файл css все работало норм.дошло дело до flexов
я создал контейнер с содержимым. и прописываю в css для него display:flex; не чего не происходит.
захожу в браузере в просмотр кода страницы. Он показывает что висит стиль от user agent stylesheet следующий: div {
display: block;
}
пробовал установить в html дисплей флекс. все норм. а вот через css не работает. подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

P.S просматривал код ни где нет перебивки, пробовал даже вызывать через ID но ему побоку.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@900&family=Ubuntu:wght@700&display=swap');
html {
    background: #3b97db;
}
#logo {
    margin: 50px 30px;
}
h1 {
    font-family:"Ubuntu";
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
.dream {
    font-size: 59px;    
    
}
.main {
       font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
       font-size: 16px;
       margin-left: 30px;
       margin-top: 50px;
       color: #ffffff;
       line-height: 2;
}

.travel {
    padding-left: 700px;
    margin-top: -450px;
}
button {
    border: 0;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    background: #ffd429;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    top: 600px;
    left: 40px;
}
h2 {
    font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 80px 500px 350px 550px;
    background: #ffffff;
    margin: 200px 0px;

p {
    font-family: "Ubuntu",sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;

}

/*.time {
    font-family: "Ubuntu"sans-serif;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: bold;
}*/

#flex {
    display: flex; 

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Первая верстка</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="part">
    <h1>С помощью верстки<br>
    я создам ту жизнь,о которой<br>
    <span class="dream">Мечтаю!</span></h1>
    <p class="main">Мои стремления + настойчивость позволят<br> мне достич
        Чего угодно.Я не верю в это.Я<br> знаю это на 100%. Меня
    Не остановить!</p>
</div>
<img class="travel" src="img/pic.png">
<button>Двигаться к мечте!</button>
<div class="two">
    <h2>Что меня ждет впереди</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="flex" class="flex">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/icon.png">
            <h3 class="time">Свободное время</h3>
            <p>Мне нужно свободное время на семью<br>
             и самое настоящее</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
             <img src="img/icon2.png">
             <h3 class="sine">Яркие путешествия</h3>
             <p>Работать откуда угодно-что может<br>
              быть лучше</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/icon3.png">
            <h3 class="launch">Создание ценности</h3>
            <p>Нет ничего сильнее,чем жить не просто<br>
             так,создавая ценность</p>
        </div>
    </div>
                                  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, дайте вопросу осмысленный заголовок, кратко описывающий суть впороса. [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё прекрасно работает, проверяйте. Причина, почему у вас не работало, понятна и проста - это незакрытая скобка. Поэтому нужно быть внимательнее при написании кода.

Дополнительно еще вам необходимо поработать с отступами, чтобы добиться правильного отображения страницы.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@900&family=Ubuntu:wght@700&display=swap');
html {
  background: #3b97db;
}

#logo {
  margin: 50px 30px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.dream {
  font-size: 59px;
}

.main {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 2;
}

.travel {
  padding-left: 700px;
  margin-top: -450px;
}

button {
  border: 0;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  background: #ffd429;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  top: 600px;
  left: 40px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 80px 500px 350px 550px;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: 200px 0px;
}

p {
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}


/*.time {
    font-family: "Ubuntu"sans-serif;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: bold;
}*/

#flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="part">
  <h1>С помощью верстки<br> я создам ту жизнь,о которой<br>
    <span class="dream">Мечтаю!</span></h1>
  <p class="main">Мои стремления + настойчивость позволят<br> мне достич Чего угодно.Я не верю в это.Я<br> знаю это на 100%. Меня Не остановить!</p>
</div>
<img class="travel" src="img/pic.png">
<button>Двигаться к мечте!</button>
<div class="two">
  <h2>Что меня ждет впереди</h2>
</div>
<div id="flex" class="flex">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="img/icon.png">
    <h3 class="time">Свободное время</h3>
    <p>Мне нужно свободное время на семью<br> и самое настоящее</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="img/icon2.png">
    <h3 class="sine">Яркие путешествия</h3>
    <p>Работать откуда угодно-что может<br> быть лучше</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="img/icon3.png">
    <h3 class="launch">Создание ценности</h3>
    <p>Нет ничего сильнее,чем жить не просто<br> так,создавая ценность</p>
  </div>
</div>
```